# Add secondary PhoneNumber to Active Directory with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to add a secondary phonenumber to an ActiveDirectory user.

I'm doing this with the

> SET-ADUSER

property.

According to the things I find online it should be done with an add parameter but this does not add the secondary phonenumber to active directory.

I can add 1 Telephone number & 1 Mobile phone number. but not a secondary.

this is my code

```
get-aduser -filter "wWWHomepage -eq $($Line.Webpage)" | Set-ADUser -Add @{otherTelephone=$i.OfficePhoneNumberSecondary } 

$userobject = get-aduser -filter "wWWHomepage -eq $($Line.Webpage)" -Properties OtherTelephone

$OtherTelephone = $userobject.OtherTelephone

Write-host $userobject has been overwritten with $OtherTelephone as Current OtherTelephone
```

the $I is a part of a csv from which I import my users.

How can I add an extra phonenumber to Active Directory using powershell?

Comment: What is the attribute syntax of your custom attribute?

Comment: My custom attribute is the $i.OfficePhoneNumberSecondary this comes from a csv (if I understand what you mean, first time working with AD and powershell, I'm a SQL SERVER boy). This should add another phonenumber to active directory

Comment: I mean: if you use Active Directory Users and Computers with the "advanced features" turned on, what do you see in the Attribute Editor for your custom attribute "otherTelephone"?

Comment: That's the problem I can't check this. the thing i found online to add the new telephone numbers is this.

-Add @{otherTelephone='555-222-1111', '555-222-3333'; otherMobile='555-222-9999' }

Comment: Your syntax is correct so it might be an issue with `$i.OfficePhoneNumberSecondary`. Add this line above `get-aduser...` to see what's going on: `Write-Host ("Secondary # to set:" + $i.OfficePhoneNumberSecondary)`